# Python как достать все значения из выпадающего списка excel файла на xlwings

Tags: python, excel

[image: Эксель файл пример]

Есть эксель файл с примерно таким списком. Как можно достать все его значения через xlwings? Ну или через что угодно на крайняк. Инфы по этому поводу почти не нашёл в инете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения значений выпадающего списка используйте `api`, на windows:

```
import xlwings as xw


book = xw.books.open(r'C:\Users\...\test.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheets['Question_Answers_Log']
print(sheet['E1'].api.Validation.Formula1)

-----------------------
yes; no; yes1; no1
```